# typeid name class different C++

Tags: c++

I am using the line typeid(obj).name() to get a class name of the object obj and I get the name 7Encrypt. But a name of the class is only Encrypt (i.e) without prefix "7".

Why happens this?

Comment: 7 is the number of letters in the class name.

Comment: Please show the code that produces the output you describe.